# MSsql select count case only if > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which select and display all values matching criteria

```
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT row_number() OVER(order by cars.make ASC,cars.model ASC) AS rn, cars.id, cars.make 
        FROM cars 
        LEFT JOIN transport ON cars.transportfrom=transport.id 
        WHERE Make in ('DAIHATSU','DODGE','JEEP','KIA','LANCIA')
) 
SELECT make, count(CASE WHEN RN BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 1 END) AS CountInResponse, count(1) AS total 
    FROM cte 
    GROUP BY make
```

I got result

```
make        |   CountInResponse |   total
DAIHATSU    |   0               |   5
DODGE       |   0               |   2
JEEP        |   0               |   14
KIA         |   10              |   39
LANCIA      |   17              |   17
```

But how to get only result which > 0?

```
make        |   CountInResponse |   total
KIA         |   10              |   39
LANCIA      |   17              |   17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( 
SELECT row_number() OVER(order by cars.make ASC,cars.model ASC) AS rn, cars.id, cars.make 
    FROM cars 
    LEFT JOIN transport ON cars.transportfrom=transport.id 
    WHERE Make in ('DAIHATSU','DODGE','JEEP','KIA','LANCIA')
) 
 SELECT make, count(CASE WHEN RN BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 1 END) AS    
 CountInResponse, count(1) AS total 
 FROM cte 
 GROUP BY make
 having count(CASE WHEN RN BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

You should add a `having` clause at the end.

Comment: It is possible to shorten this query?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin..i didn't get that.